# Issue with my WHERE clause: mulitle condition issue

Tags: sql

Hello All I'm having a little bit of an issue in my WHERE statement. Below I need to make sure the user has c.Options = 'TA' BUT also make sure that it overlooks (not include) c.Options = 'PT'... Below is what I am currently working with...

*The c is for Coverage*

```
 WHERE
  c.Options = 'TA' AND c.Options NOT LIKE '%PT%'
```

Thanks for all your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: The second filter isn't needed.  IF Options = 'TA' then the second filter will never be true.

Comment: Why do you need the `AND` condition while the 1st condition is sufficient to omit things?

Comment: What are 'TA' and 'PT' if you don't mind?

Comment: I need to EXCLUDE looking at c.Options = 'PT', basically when I run this query i don't get what I need because c.Options can include 'PT' I want to exclude looking at this...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR:  You automatically filter out anything that contains PT with your first filter, cause you are only looking at options that have a value of 'TA'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to aggregate for this logic:

```
select c.user
from c
group by c.user
having sum(case when c.options = 'TA' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when c.options = 'PT' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The first part says there is a "TA" option.  The second says there is no "PT" option.